# UIScrollView contentSize isn't working, it's not autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `contentView` with stuff inside the `contentView`. Everything is created programmatically, not in IB (my way of avoiding different screen size constraint messes in IB). Autolayout is OFF on the corresponding NIB, so that's not a problem. All code below is located in `viewDidAppear`:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, screenHeight)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1200)];
[scrollView addSubview: contentView];
[scrollView setContentSize:contentView.frame.size];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1200);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

It scrolls a little bit on iPhone 5, but only about 20 pixels more than the screen size. On iPhone 4 it scrolls all the way down to 1200 pixels, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. I was loading all of my elements inside the `viewDidAppear`, not just the `scrollView`.

By moving `contentView` declaration and all the elements inside of `contentView` into it's own function then declared in `viewDidLoad`, it resolved the issue and everything loads just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, screenHeight - 65)];
```

Comment: It did actually add a little bit of scrolling, but unfortunately the problem still exists; it's not scrolling anywhere near the required 1200px.